# LibCurl & Sql Commands

Tags: c++, sql, variables, libcurl

i'm a beginner in c++, and i have 2 small problem.

1 - I want to get the public ip address of the user. To do this I use curl like this :

```
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode verif;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ifconfig.me/?action=render");
    verif = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

But when I run the program it writes the IP but I'm not sure how to store it into a variable. What should I do to achieve this?

2 - I want to send a request to a database, but I have some issues with my syntax.
My code :

```
int query_state = mysql_query(db, "INSERT INTO `account` (`id`, `id_user`, `ip`, `last_join`) VALUES (NULL, '" << id << "', '" << ip_user << "', '" << date << "')");
```

But i have an error with the "<<". The error is here in the request : (NULL, ' " **<<** id

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in the IP address and nothing else, query https://ifconfig.me/ip instead of https://ifconfig.me/?action=render. And then use a [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) callback to save that output to a variable, such as a `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
size_t write_str(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
{
    size_t numBytes = size * nmemb;
    static_cast<std::string*>(userdata)->append(ptr, numBytes);
    return numBytes;
}

...

std::string ip_user;
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ifconfig.me/ip");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_str);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ip_user);
CURLcode verif = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

---

As for the database, you can't use `<<` to concatenate strings the way you are trying to.  That is why you are getting errors from the compiler.

If you really want to use `<<` for concatenation then you need to use a `std::ostringstream` to gather up the substrings, and then you can call its `str()` method to extract the completed `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "INSERT INTO account (id, id_user, ip, last_join) VALUES (NULL, '" << id << "', '" << ip_user << "', '" << date << "')";
std::string sql = oss.str();
int query_state = mysql_query(db, sql.c_str());
```

Otherwise, just use normal string `+` concatenation instead:

```cpp
std::string sql = "INSERT INTO account (id, id_user, ip, last_join) VALUES (NULL, '" + id + "', '" + ip_user + "', '" + date + "')";
int query_state = mysql_query(db, sql.c_str());
```

With that said, note that this manual build-up of the SQL statement is susceptible to SQL injection attacks.  To avoid such attacks, you have to escape your input strings, such as with [`mysql_real_escape_string_quote()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string-quote.html), so that attackers can't give you malformed input that corrupts your SQL statement into performing malicious actions, eg:

```cpp
std::string sql_escape(MYSQL *db, const std::string &s char quote = '\'')
{
    std::string escaped;
    escaped.resize((s.length() * 2) + 1);
    escaped.resize(mysql_real_escape_string_quote(db, &escaped[0], s.c_str(), s.length(), quote));
    return escaped;
}
```

```cpp
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "INSERT INTO account (id, id_user, ip, last_join) VALUES (NULL, " << sql_escape(db, id) << ", " << sql_escape(db, ip_user) << ", " << sql_escape(db, date) << ")";
std::string sql = oss.str();
...
```

```cpp
std::string sql = "INSERT INTO account (id, id_user, ip, last_join) VALUES (NULL, " + sql_escape(db, id) + ", " + sql_escape(db, ip_user) + ", " + sql_escape(db, date) + ")";
...
```

A better option is to use a *parameterized query* instead.  Not only will that plug the hole for such attacks, but it will also let the DB handle any necessary escaping of input strings for you, eg:

```cpp
std::string sql = "INSERT INTO account (id, id_user, ip, last_join) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)";
MYSQL_BIND params[3] = {};

params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
params[0].buffer = &id[0]; // or id.data() in C++17
params[0].buffer_length = params[0].length = id.length();

params[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
params[1].buffer = &ip_user[0]; // or ip_user.data() in C++17
params[1].buffer_length = params[1].length = ip_user.length();

params[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
params[2].buffer = &date[0]; // or date.data() in C++17
params[2].buffer_length = params[2].length = date.length();

MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(db);
mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, sql.c_str(), sql.length());
mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, params);
mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);
mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
```